# JavaScript failing after second ajax request using submit/selection button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, d3.js

I'm guessing this error has to do with asynchronous programming, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it after looking at various examples on here...

I have a basic form that should do a post request and then it produces a d3 graph based on the form selection value...

```
<form id="target" method="post">
<select name="len" id="len">
<option value="sel">--Select--</option>
    <option value="year">Most Recent Year</option>
    <option value="all">All Data</option>
</select>
    <input type = "submit"class="btn" value="Submit"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.btn').on('click',function(){

var myvar = $('select[name=len]').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'dbquery_o2_select.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'var':myvar},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (result){

        // produce a d3 graph here

    },
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus){
        alert(textStatus);
    }   
});

return false; });

});
```

Upon the second "submit", I get an error saying that 'sampledate' (which is an associated name in the ajax return array named 'result') is undefined.

Thanks in advance for any help. Let me know if you need more info!

Comment: It sounds like your POST request isn't returning the data you expect the second time. Did you check that?

Comment: Yeah, I checked it in firebug and the post is successful with the data that I want the second time.

Comment: It's really hard to say what's going on without seeing what you do in `dbquery_o2_select.php` and what kind of json response you get back, what comes to mind is either what Lars said or that if you need the result from the first call to allow the second call to be executed successfully, that you sent the second ajax request without waiting the end of the first computation.

Comment: I found a solution after checking the output in the console. It was because I was defining a function "Array.prototype.max" with a return value inside the success part and upon the second request, it appended these return values to the "result" object. Anyway, it works now, but how do I get it to overwrite the other graph? It is placing the new graph directly below it.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, I issue d3.select("svg").remove() to remove the graph. Thanks!